# Get custom category from specific category posts

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, archive, posts

I've been searching the way to do it but no good. The title may be confusing, let me explain my problem...

I have the archive page (the main category), then I've posts inside that category and inside the posts I've more categories (custom type category).

- **Archive** (w/ Category Something w/ Posts about This, This, That)

  - **Category** (Something)

    - **Posts** (Posts about Something)

      - **Custom Categories** (Posts categorized This, This, That)

What I want is, get all the custom categories inside the posts from that category and put a list inside the archive page.

What I find is how to list all of the custom categories, but I just want the ones given to the posts inside the main category. I would like to have answers, and really would appreciate to anyone that helps me with this.

**Example** (Series):

- (**Category**) Game of Thrones

  - (**Posts**) Synopsis Episode 1; Synopsis Episode 2; ... etc etc

    - (**Custom Category**) Synopsis Episode 1: fantasy, blood; Synopsis Episode 2: nude, incest; etc etc...

Then on Category (Game of Thrones) there's the category main synopsis and a list of what the episodes contain like:

- Blood, Fantasy, Incest, Nude, etc etc...

Also a list of episodes, with their title, to go to the synopsis.

Comment: Are you want to list out the custom category of custom post type?

Comment: @kausha-mehta No, not of custom post type, custom category of default posts. A list of custom categories that are inside the posts, then I want to retrieve those custom categories and list them on the Category Page, the one where the posts are.

Comment: Have you reigistered any custom taxonomy for your custom categories or you are using default taxonomy that is category.

Comment: @SunilChaudhary I'm using the default taxonomy as main category.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a separate category page for your Custom Category like category-(your_required_cat_id).php.
copy your theme category.php file and make it like category-25.php where 25 is your category id of the required category.
So, when you click on the category link, this will automatically show listing of all posts of that category only.

Comment: Well I believe that's not what I'm looking for. I added a example to explain myself better. Thanks for trying to understand my question anyway.